# Преобразование числа из float в int после умножения в pygame

Tags: python, pygame, float

Пишу простой кликер на pygame.

В момент когда игрок покупает "автокликер", что будет кликать автоматически (эту часть кода я еще не реализовал) хочу увиличить цену покупки автокликера на 10%, чтобы был какой то челлендж.
Для этого умножаю цену автокликера на 1.1, чтобы получить 10%, однако после этой операции умножения, тип переменной меняется с int на float(в общем то так и должно быть).
Из за этого при дальнейших покупках число знаков после запятой увеличивается в сотни раз и мешает играть загораживая экран.

Пытался менять тип переменной с float на int прописыванием int(autoClickMultiplierPrice) как после операции умножения, так и перед ней в основном цикле(и не в основном тоже), но это ни к чему не приводило и тип оставался float.

Как изменить тип переменной с float на int, чтобы все нормально работало после умножения на 1.1?

```py
while mainLoop:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            mainLoop = False

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
            pos = event.pos

            if 200 < pos[0] < 480 and 180 < pos[1] < 470:
                coinCounter += 1

            if 490 < pos[0] < 670 and 40 < pos[1] < 90 and coinCounter >= autoClickMultiplierPrice:
                coinCounter -= autoClickMultiplierPrice
                autoClickMultiplierPrice = autoClickMultiplierPrice * 1.1
                int(autoClickMultiplierPrice)

            else:
                break
```

Comment: Функция `int()` не меняет само число, о возвращает новое. Так что вам всего-лишь не хватает присваивания его куда нибудь. `autoClickMultiplierPrice = int(autoClickMultiplierPrice * 1.1)`

Comment: @GrAnd спасибо! действительно теперь все работает

Comment: А что вам мешает хранить и считать `float` для большей точности, а при показе округлять число до `int`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. в 4 строке с конца (где функция int), не было присвоено значение. int не меняет значение, а возвращает новое. Решение:

   ```
   autoClickMultiplierPrice = int(autoClickMultiplierPrice)
   ```
2. Проблема с кучей знаком после запятой не относится к питону. Это проблема двоичной системы. Решить можно с использованием встроенной функции `round`, Решение:

   ```
   price = autoClickMultiplierPrice * 1.1
   autoClickMultiplierPrice = round(price, 3)
   ```

Comment: Спасибо, учту, что есть такая функция